# How to separate a concatenated string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have a concatenated string in a column as `3-123456-ABC`.
I need to have the values split by hyphen and displayed in `3` separate columns.
Am initially trying for the first `column` itself where i am failing. Please guide. Below is my query:

```
select SUBSTR('3-123456-ABC', 3, Instr('3-123456-ABC', '-', -1, 1) -1) from dual;
```

The above query gives me result as `123456-ABC` which is incorrect. Please guide.

Comment: See the linked question above for a virtually identical question answered recently - it has several techniques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer. Did it via regex :

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR ('3-1896042-TEMP', '[^-]+', 1, 1)    AS part_1
,       REGEXP_SUBSTR ('3-1896042-TEMP', '[^-]+', 1, 2)    AS part_2
,       REGEXP_SUBSTR ('3-1896042-TEMP', '[^-]+', 1, 3)    AS part_3
FROM    dual
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the manual for SUBSTR we can see that:

- The first argument is the string to cut
- The second argument is the place to start cutting (why did you put 3 when you want the first character i.e. you should put 1)
- The third argument is the length of characters to cut. If you've determined that the first hyphen occurs at index 2, you only want one char, so the length you want is given by the formula "index_of_end minus index_of_start" - and index of start is 1

INSTR can be made to search backwards by setting its start index parameter to negative, but i'm not sure why you do this.. For getting the "3" you want to search forwards

```
SUBSTR('3-123456-ABC', 1,               INSTR('3-123456-ABC', '-')   - 1)
                       ^                ^^^^^                        ^^^
                 start cutting       the end index ...        minus the start index (1)
```

Later for getting the last hyphen you can search backwards:

```
SUBSTR('3-123456-ABC', INSTR('3-123456-ABC', '-', -1)   + 1)
                       ^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^    ^^^
               start cutting         the last hyphen    not including the hyphen
```

When you don't pass a length argument to SUBSTR it cuts to the end of the string.